# Unable to export PATH in JupyterLab

Tags: shell, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I'm trying to execute shell commands inside an .ipynb file in JupyterLab, but I'm unable to export PATH. Here's my .zshrc file:

```
!echo | cat ~/.zshrc
```

The result:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/adam/anaconda3/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/Library/TeX/texbin
[ -f "/Users/adam/.ghcup/env" ] && source "/Users/adam/.ghcup/env" # ghcup-env

# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/Users/adam/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.zsh' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/adam/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/adam/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/Users/adam/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

Then I tried to source it and then echo the path:

```
!source ~/.zshrc
!echo $PATH
```

however, the PATH didn't change:

```
/Users/adam/opt/anaconda3/envs/xeus/bin:/Users/adam/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

The commands below yielded the same result.

```
!export PATH=$PATH:/Library/TeX/texbin
!echo $PATH
```

Do anyone have any idea what's going on?

Comment: You might need to restart JupyterLab. I imagine that each command may be executed in a subshell so running `source script` would have no effect on the consecutive commands (it does not change the running parent shell).

Comment: @krassowski Restarted several times. Always end up with the same PATH. It seems that the ~/.zshrc didn't take effect. Although, thank you for pointing out that the shell commands may execute in a subshell. I tried to write commands like this: ```!export PATH=$PATH:/Library/TeX/texbin;echo $PATH```, and the PATH was successfully changed. This already solved my problem.

Comment: Glad it helped! Please consider adding it as an answer to your own question for visibility as it will help others to find it quickly.